# ser.write() hex string Raspberry

Tags: python, serial-port, send

I have a problem with sending/reading hex data over RS485. I'm not sure if I send the correct string over the serial port.
The hex code is: `E1 14 75 81`. I have read that i can write:

```
data = "\xE1\x14\x75\x81" 
ser.write(data)
```

To check if the correct code is send, I added `print(ser.write(data))` But I get this Output back:

```
True
4
▒
```

I also want to read the answer of the hex string. For this i only have to added `ser.read()`

Here the ful code:
    import serial
    import struct

```
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate=19200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )

    print(ser.isOpen())
    data = "\xE1\x14\x75\x81"
    ser.write(data)
    print(ser.write(data))
    ser.read()
    print(ser.read())
    ser.close()
```

Many thank for your help!

Comment: ser.write returns the number of bytes written (4) ... if you try and print hex it will look really wrong (since its not ascii ...)  try instead `print(repr(ser.read()))` as this will give you a better idea of what you are getting back or `print(map(hex,map(ord,ser.read())))` would also give you the appropriate representation ... or even `binascii.hexlify(ser.read()))` (but im not sure if `ser.read` only reads a single byte by default ...)

Comment: If your RS485 transmitter isn't connected to a shared wire (i.e. to which your receiver is also connected), or doesn't have a loopback to the receiver, or the remote system isn't echoing what you send, then you won't receive anything using the ser.read() command.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help! `print(map(hex,map(ord,ser.read())))` works perfect. But you are wirght. `ser.read()` reads only a single byte. did you know how i can change it? I expect 46 bytes.

Comment: Okay i found the solution! `ser.read(46)` works..